# What does juvenile taste mean (and why)?

Tags: adjectives, connotations

I read the following in Stephen Budiansky's "Journey to the Edge of Reason":

> ... his perpetually juvenile tastes in art, music, and decorations, ...

What connotation does *juvenile* have in "juvenile taste"? Does it imply not *maturing* with age?

Comment: Yes. He continued to like the kind of things that usually only young people like.

Comment: Can the downvoter be just enough to provide a justification? I searched enough to see if such a phrase already exists in English. Bad elements of SO.

Comment: "disapproving: silly and typical of a child" - Cambridge Dictionary. Downvotes may be given for perceived lack of research.

Comment: When composing a question it's always advisable to include the research. Looking up the word "juvenile" in an online dictionary should have been your first stop. If it was, and you still felt confused you should explain why. You can still edit your question and clarify. There's nothing bad about fixing a question to improve it. The question title asks what "juvenile tastes" means.

Comment: I thought I had searched long enough, I can't say that I carried out research, however. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**juvenile** here taste means **childish**, not mature or grown up.

juvenile taste in art or books versus a mature taste in art or books.

A dictionary entry here might be misleading but there is no doubt that juvenile means childish or like a child or young person here.